# Domains of higher powers of two unbounded self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $A : D(A) \rightarrow H$ and $B : D(B) \rightarrow H$ be two unbounded self-adjoint operators that are densely defined on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose we know that $D(A) = D(B)$. Are there sufficient conditions for the equality $D(A^k) = D(B^k)$ to be true for positive integers all integers $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$? Is there an example where this equality fails?

I guess this is true if $A$ and $B$ also commute with each other. But is there a more general sufficient condition?

Comment: Even commuting is not enough: Let $A$ arbitrary with $D(A^2)\neq D(A)$ and $B$ the identity operator restricted to $D(A)$, then $D(A)=D(B)$ but $D(A^2)\neq D(B^2) = D(B)$. However, here $B$ is not a closed operator.

Comment: But we know that A and B are self-adjoint. Hence, we are assuming that the domains are closed. But, yes, I get the idea. Now I am confused for the commuting case as well.

Comment: If you are assuming both domains are closed and dense, then the operators are bounded and defined everywhere.

Comment: Haudor probably had in mind that the operators are closed (which is a consequence of self adjointness) and not that the domains are closed. Then the question persists. Maybe one can find counterexamples by choosing $B$ nilpotent, at least then $D(B^k)$ stabilizes at some point, whereas in general this is false.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I meant the operators are closed. If it helps, I am particularly interested in the case when both operators are negative definite.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is an example why this could be generally hard.

Let $A :D(A) \rightarrow L^2(0,1)$ with $D(A) = \lbrace u \in H^2(0,1); u_x(0)=u_x(1)=0 \rbrace$  where $H^2(0,1)$ is the set of elements $L^2(0,1)$ that are least twice weakly differentiable. Additionally, for an element $a \in L^{\infty}(0,1)$ we define the multiplication operator $M_a : L^2(0,1) \rightarrow L^2(0,1)$ as $(M_af)(x)= a(x)f(x)$ for a.e $x \in (0,1)$. Then $D(A) = D(A-M_a) \subset H^2(0,1)$. Additionally, $D(A)^2 \subset H^4(0,1)$ but $D((A-M_a)^2) \not\subset H^4(0,1)$. For example, if $\mathbf{1}$ is the function taking value $1$ everywhere on $(0,1)$, then  $\mathbf{1} \in D(A) = D(A-M_a)$, and $\mathbf{1} \in D(A^2)$. But $\mathbf{1} \notin D((A-M_a)^2)$ if $a$ is non-differentiable. The situation doesn't change if we replace $A$ by $A+\mathbb{I}$ with $\mathbb{I}$ being the identity operator.